# Merging Multiple sorted linkedlists into One

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to write a program to merge two sorted linked lists.
But its not merging them.
it seems like the error is in representing head pointer.
how to represent head pointer? is my way correct.
I am facing a lot of problems using pointers pls give me some suggestions especially head pointer

## merge two sorted linkedlist

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next =None
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
    def push(self,ndata):
        nnode = Node(ndata)
        nnode.next = self.head
        self.head = nnode
    def addNodeToList(self,ndata):
        nnode = Node(ndata)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = nnode
            return
        last = self.head
        while last.next is not None:
            last = last.next
        last.next = nnode
    
    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp is not None:
            print(temp.data,end = ' ')
            temp = temp.next
def merge(first,second):
        dummy=linkedlist()
        temp = dummy.head
        temp1=first.head
        temp2=second.head
        while temp1 and temp2:
            if temp1.data<temp2.data:
                temp=temp1
                temp.next=None
                temp1=temp1.next
                print('\n1..')
            elif temp1.data>=temp2.data:
                temp=temp2
                temp.next=None
                temp2=temp2.next
                print('\n2..')
        if temp1 is not None:
            temp.next= temp1
            print('\n3..')
        else:
            temp.next=temp2
            print('\n4..')
        print('Done')
        return  dummy          
if __name__=='__main__':
    
    list1=linkedlist()
    list1.addNodeToList(10)
    list1.addNodeToList(20)
    list1.addNodeToList(30)
    list1.addNodeToList(40)
    list1.addNodeToList(50)
    
    list2=linkedlist()
    # Create linked list 2 : 5->15->18->35->60 
    list2.addNodeToList(5)
    list2.addNodeToList(15)
    list2.addNodeToList(18)
    list2.addNodeToList(35)
    list2.addNodeToList(60)
    list1.printList()
    
    print()
    list2.printList()
    
    a=merge(list1,list2)
    a.printList()

Expected output is a single merged linkedlist
```

Comment: What would be the excpected output of the merged linkedlist?

Comment: Instead of manually trying to add to the list, why not just call `dummy.addNodeToList()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the `addNodeToList()` function so why not use it?

```
def merge(first,second):
    dummy=linkedlist()
    temp1=first.head
    temp2=second.head
    while temp1 and temp2:
        if temp1.data<temp2.data:
            dummy.addNodeToList(temp1.data)
            temp1=temp1.next
        else:
            dummy.addNodeToList(temp2.data)
            temp2=temp2.next
    while temp1:
        dummy.addNodeToList(temp1.data)
        temp1=temp1.next
    while temp2:
        dummy.addNodeToList(temp2.data)
        temp2=temp2.next
    return  dummy
```

Comment: thanks a lot... but i dnt know what i did wrong in my method...

Comment: @GarvitTyagi As mentioned in the other answer, you do `temp = dummy.head` and then use `temp` for the rest of the code. For example, `temp=temp2` - this modifies `temp` but not `dummy.head`.

Answer (score 0):

You are never adding to `dummy` in your code - you do `temp = dummy.head` and then you reassign `temp` and the `dummy` list is never updated. Here is an approach:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList: # classes in python must be in CamelCase
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def push(self, ndata):
        nnode = Node(ndata)
        nnode.next = self.head
        self.head = nnode

    def addNodeToList(self, ndata):
        nnode = Node(ndata)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = nnode
            return
        last = self.head
        while last.next is not None:
            last = last.next
        last.next = nnode

    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp is not None:
            print(temp.data, end = ' ')
            temp = temp.next

    def walk_list(self):
        temp = self.head
        values = []
        while temp is not None:
            values.append(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next
        return values

def merge(first, second):
    values1 = first.walk_list()
    values1.extend(second.walk_list())
    dummy = LinkedList()
    for v in sorted(values1):
        dummy.push(v)
    return dummy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = LinkedList()
    list1.addNodeToList(10)
    list1.addNodeToList(20)
    list1.addNodeToList(30)
    list1.addNodeToList(40)
    list1.addNodeToList(50)
    list2 = LinkedList()
    # Create linked list 2 : 5->15->18->35->60
    list2.addNodeToList(5)
    list2.addNodeToList(15)
    list2.addNodeToList(18)
    list2.addNodeToList(35)
    list2.addNodeToList(60)
    list1.printList()
    print()
    list2.printList()
    a = merge(list1, list2)
    a.printList()
```